# Speed up SVD in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, batch-processing, matrix-multiplication, svd

I am doing some classification task for CIFAR10 with Pytorch and for each iteration I have to do some preprocessing on each batch before I would be able to feed forward to the model.
Below is the code for the preprocessing part on each batch:

```py
S = torch.zeros((batch_size, C, H, W))
for i in range(batch_size):
    img = batch[i, :, :, :]
    for c in range(C):                
        U, _, V = torch.svd(img[c])
        S[i, c] = U[:, 0].view(-1, 1).matmul(V[:, 0].view(1, -1))
```

However, this calculation is very slow. Is there any way that I could speed up this code?

Comment: I fixed the code. So is there a way to speed up this version?

Comment: You could try using SVD from numpy and then use [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) to accelerate it.

Comment: Numba does not provide any speedup for SVD calculation.

Answer (score 0):

**Batched calculation**

Assuming you have PyTorch >= 1.2.0 then batched SVD is supported so you can use

```
U, _, V = torch.svd(batch)
S = U[:, :, :, 0].unsqueeze(3) @ V[:, :, :, 0].unsqueeze(2)
```

which I found to be a little faster on average than the iterative version.

---

**Truncated SVD (CPU only)**

If you don't have cuda acceleration you could use truncated SVD to avoid computing the unnecessary singular values/vectors. Unfortunately PyTorch doesn't support truncated SVD and AFAIK there's no batched or GPU version available. There are two options I'm aware of

- [`scipy.sparse.linalg.svds`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.svds.html)
- [`sklearn.sparse.linalg.randomized_svd`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.extmath.randomized_svd.html)

Both of these allow you to choose the number of components to return. In OP's original question we only want the first component.

Even though I'm not using it on sparse matrices I found `svds` with `k=1` to be about 10x faster than `torch.svd` on CPU tensors. I found that `randomized_svd` was only about 2x faster. Your results will depend on the actual data. Also, `svds` should be a little more accurate than `randomized_svd`. Keep in mind there are going to be small differences between these results and the `torch.svd` results, but they should be negligible.

```py
import scipy.sparse.linalg as sp
import numpy as np

S = torch.zeros((batch_size, C, H, W))
for i in range(batch_size):
    img = batch[i, :, :, :]
    for c in range(C):
        u, _, v = sp.svds(img[c], k=1)
        S[i, c] = torch.from_numpy(np.outer(u, v))
```

---

Comment: I tried this before and there wasn't any improvement as torch.svd() could be on GPU. I wonder if these two for loops could be converted to batch-wise calculations.

Answer (score 0):

PyTorch now has [speed optimised Linear Algebra operations](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.8.0/linalg.html) analogous to numpy's `linalg` module, including `torch.linalg.svd`:

> The implementation of SVD on CPU uses the LAPACK routine *?gesdd* (a divide-and-conquer algorithm) instead of *?gesvd* for speed. Analogously, the SVD on GPU uses the cuSOLVER routines *gesvdj* and *gesvdjBatched* on CUDA 10.1.243 and later, and uses the MAGMA routine gesdd on earlier versions of CUDA.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very interesting tool for operating SVD in batches: [batch_svd](https://github.com/KinglittleQ/torch-batch-svd#1-introduction)